# How to run VtsHalWifiSupplicantV1_0Target test case

Tags: android, android-vts

When I ran "run vts -m VtsHalWifiSupplicantV1_0Target", I get 0 result from it.

vts-tf > run vts -m VtsHalWifiSupplicantV1_0Target
...
10-15 09:56:06 I/ResultReporter: Invocation finished in 48s. PASSED: 0, FAILED: 0, MODULES: 2 of 2

Do I need to write some code to run the vts test case?
I expected to get something passed or failed. How can I get results?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two reasons why a VTS test run would have that result.

1. The [HAL Testability Checker](https://source.android.com/compatibility/vts/hal-testability) decided to skip the test. This could be because the HAL you want to test is not running on the target or you try to run an x86 test on an x64 platform.
2. `vts-tradefed` will call the test binary with the `--gtest_list_tests` option in order to get the amount of tests. If this call fails `vts-tradefed` will assume you have zero test cases.

In any case you can get more information by checking the host logs.

```
zcat $ANDROID_HOST_OUT/vts/android-vts/logs/latest/inv_*/host_log*.txt.gz | less
```